# Bubble sort of random integers in scala

Tags: scala, random, bubble-sort

I'm new in Scala programming language so in this Bubble sort I need to generate 10 random integers instead of right it down like the code below
any suggestions?

```
object BubbleSort {

  def bubbleSort(array: Array[Int]) = {
    def bubbleSortRecursive(array: Array[Int], current: Int, to: Int): Array[Int] = {
        println(array.mkString(",") + "    current -> " + current + ", to -> " + to)
        to match {
          case 0 => array
          case _ if(to == current) => bubbleSortRecursive(array, 0, to - 1)
          case _ =>
            if (array(current) > array(current + 1)) {
            var temp = array(current + 1)
            array(current + 1) = array(current)
            array(current) = temp
          }
          bubbleSortRecursive(array, current + 1, to)
        }
    }
    bubbleSortRecursive(array, 0, array.size - 1)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sortedArray = bubbleSort(Array(10,9,11,5,2))
    println("Sorted Array -> " + sortedArray.mkString(","))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scala.util.Random` for generation. `nextInt` method takes `maxValue` argument, so in the code sample, you'll generate list of 10 int values from 0 to 100.

```scala
val r = scala.util.Random
for (i <- 1 to 10) yield r.nextInt(100)
```

You can find more info [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-generate-random-numbers-characters-sequences-in-scala/) or [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Random.html)

Comment: Where should I put this loop exaclly ? I'm confused.

Comment: as a replacement to your hardcoded array, before passing it to bubbleSort

So, like 
```
val r = scala.util.Random
val arr = for (i <- 1 to 10) yield r.nextInt(100)
bubbleSort(arr.toArray)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [this](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/ULYckaz/0):

```
import scala.util.Random
val sortedArray = (1 to 10).map(_ => Random.nextInt).toArray
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it this way.

```
val solv1 = Random.shuffle( (1 to 100).toList).take(10)
val solv2 = Array.fill(10)(Random.nextInt)
```